# What does the phrase "be matched by GitHub" mean?

Tags: meaning

> You can also sponsor the work of LaTeX team members through the GitHub sponsor program at the moment for Frank, David and Joseph. Your contribution will **be matched by GitHub** in the first year and goes 100% to the developers.

What does it mean by "be matched by GitHub"?

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, this is saying that GitHub will contribute an amount of money equal to your contribution. The phrase *matching contribution* is often used to describe the act of employers paying into employees' retirement funds at a rate equal to that of the employees' personal contributions.

Similar constructions are *matching donation* and *matching gift*. See the [Wikipedia page for **matching funds**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_funds) for more context.

Comment: So matching contribution means that someone matches the contribution. Now we're up to speed. The vanilla purpose of the verb.